# Using C with assembly on windows

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to compile and link a simple c and assembly program together.
The assembly program should simply return a value of 10 back to the c
program and the c program should output it to the screen.

I have two files 1) main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int my_asm();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int r = my_asm();
    printf("Value: %i\n", r);

    return 0;
}
```

and 2) file.asm

```
global _my_asm

    section .text
_my_asm:
    mov eax, 10
    ret
```

I first compile the assembler program like so at the command line:

```
nasm -f win32 file.asm
```

This results in 'file.obj' being created.

Secondly I use gcc to link main.c and file.obj together to get my exe file:

```
gcc main.c file.obj -o main
```

This creates my main.exe file as expected but when i run main.exe I get no output?

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Are you currently doing a course on Udemy out of curiosity?

Comment: Are you getting a window though, then it closes immediately? What exact behavior are you getting?

Comment: I certainly am.

Comment: Ha, I think we're doing the same course (British dude).

Comment: Ah ha! x86 Assembly Language Programming Masters course? You get this far yet? Did you get it to work? (Irish American dude)

Comment: Didn't see your previous reply. I am at the command line running the commands. I run the main.exe file but it does not produce the expected output: Value: 10 Make sense? It outputs nothing and goes back to command prompt

Comment: Ya, that's the one. Honestly, I quit following him after awhile. I was hoping to upgrade my existing knowledge, but I haven't found him to be a very good teacher. I don't see anything obvious here though. I'd load it up in `gdb` and see what's happening. Most things are more apparent in a debugger.

Comment: So does it work if you simply use a C file? I doubt this has anything to do with your assembly.

Comment: I can get it working if I use `nasm -f elf32 file.asm -o file.obj`, and `gcc main.c file.obj -m32 -o main` (for linux). `./main` correctly prints `Value: 10`. Try that but replacing `elf32` with `win32`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. Yes, I actually have compiled and run the c file only and that worked perfectly fine. So, it's definitely something with the linking process? gcc command? I'm not sure

Comment: Ah your on linux there though right? I'm doing this from windows cmd prompt. Same thing the guy's doing in the course

Comment: I'll try again. I noticed your gcc command is a little different

Comment: Ya, try just replacing the assembler output format so it matches what you had before. I'm using `ELF` because that's what Unix uses.

Comment: I don't see any reason why that asm should cause any problems, and without an error message too. What happens if you print something before you invoke the asm? What happens if you just link the asm but don't invoke it?

Comment: Ya, I don't know how yours even compiled. Without `-m32` to specify 32-bit, I get errors. I also changed `_my_asm` to `my_asm` in all places. Idk if that's a Windows thing though because I've only practiced on ParrotOS.

Comment: Hey so I got it working. I changed the gcc command I was using and added the -m32 parameter. That worked perfectly! Thanks so much

Comment: Good to hear. It's bizarre that it even compiled for you originally. I get "incompatible output" errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what that teacher is saying then. Thanks for the heads up. I did think he was hit and miss alright. I'm gonna finish the course out though.

Comment: This is the first time I have posted here. Great to know there is super helpful people here. Thanks again. I spent a few hours head scratching on google with that one. Hahaha!

Comment: what do you see when you disassemble the final binary (whatever-objdump -d main, and examine the call and what is done with the return with respect to your function?  likewise if you make the function in C in a separate file what does the diassembly show of that function and how does that compare to your asm function?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: On Linux, the linker will refuse to link an ELF32 `.o` into a 64-bit executable. And yes, decorating asm symbol names with a leading `_` is something that 32-bit code on Windows does, and so does MacOS.  GNU/Linux doesn't, not since the mid 90s when Linux used the a.out object format instead of ELF.  64-bit code on Windows also doesn't, so I'd have expected a symbol-not-found error on Windows with `gcc` without `-m32`.  (Or a bitness mismatch error - it would be insane for the toolchain to not detect that.)

Comment: @Carcigenicate By the way, can you recommend a good x86 assembly course online? The guy on udemy is wrecking my head now. He's jumping into stuff without any decent prior explanations? Thanks

Comment: @user309554 No unfortunately. I learned basic x86 assembly at a technical college. It's proving to be a difficult topic to find good introductory material on.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No problem. I'm going to try this guy, if it's any use to you: [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWlAg-pwMsM&list=PLan2CeTAw3pFOq5qc9urw8w7R-kvAT8Yb&index=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved.

I needed to add the -m32 flag to the gcc command:

gcc main.c file.obj -m32 -o main

The program then ran correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: So your gcc defaulted to `-m64`, and didn't error when you linked a `nasm -fwin32` output file into a 64-bit `.exe`?  That's very surprising, you should have got a symbol not found error for `my_asm`, because Win64 doesn't use a leading `_`.  And more importantly, linkers should know that 32 and 64-bit x86 machine code aren't fully compatible and refuse to link them.  If you have a cygwin or mingw version of `file`, you can do `file foo.exe` to see if it's 32 or 64-bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi Peter, thanks for your comment. So, I'm following a beginners assembly course on Udemy and the teacher was linking the programs using gcc without the -m32 flag. It was all working for him (including the expected output from the executable), which is really strange? I was getting no compilation or linker errors (when not using the -m32 flag). I was not getting the expected output from the executable though? I'm on Windows 10 btw, has that something to do with it?

Comment: It's not strange that it worked for someone else if they they installed MinGW32 instead of MinGW64, then `gcc`'s default would be `-m32`.  (Same for cygwin if they installed 32-bit Cygwin).  On an actual GNU/Linux system, `gcc`'s default matches the bitness of the rest of user-space, but that's because it's installed from distro packages.  On Windows where you install GCC yourself, it's up to you whether you choose a 32 or 64-bit GCC.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, we installed MinGW32. Still doesn't explain why his executable's were working and mine were not. Any ideas?

Comment: If your `gcc -m32` is different from `gcc` for you, then your GCC is something other than MingGW32, I think (been a long time since I actually used GCC under Windows, but I do know GCC in general well enough to be pretty sure.  Although not getting a linker error without `-m32` casts doubt on `-m64` being the default).  Maybe you have another GCC install earlier in your `PATH`?  Use `gcc -v` to see what "target" it was configured for.  If you're using bash, use `type -a gcc` to see all the `gcc` executables in your PATH - the first one is what will run if you don't use an explicit path.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah ha! ok, I'll take a closer look at the PATH set up. There could be some conflict there then. Thanks again.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi again, from a windows cmd prompt, I ran gcc -v as you suggested. One of the lines said _Target: mingw32._ What does this suggest then?

Comment: That does sound like it should be defaulting to 32-bit already, so IDK.

Comment: @PeterCordes Also, I did look at my PATH under user and system variables and there is nothing to suggest another GCC install in the PATH, only the one that was installed in the course which is at C:\MinGW\bin

Comment: Yeah very strange. I appreciate the help though. Thanks again.